# Insert multiple rows, after other multiple rows in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I think a picture will say a thousand words:

[image]

Basically I want to copy and paste the bottom tabbed text (after "Exchange:") to the right of the lines at the start (not tabbed). Is there a way to do this in Notepad++?

Comment: Please, don't post example with picture, post text and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

copy the first column to excel sheet (ex. A column ) then copy the bottom tabbed text to another column in same sheet (ex. B column ). then copy paste hole text (column A & B) from sheet to notepad++.

Comment: This certainly accomplishes what I intended but it uses another program (excel). Is there a way to do it with only NP++?

Comment: it's little bit tricky but you can do it by shift+alt cmd on notepade++.